# Create App Engine project via API

Tags: google-app-engine

I would need to automate the creation of new App Engine projects. Is this possible? I see there is a Google Cloud SQL Admin API which can create new Cloud SQL instances, but what about App Engine? Is there anything similar?

Update:
We have developed an application that runs on GAE and uses Cloud SQL and plenty of API integration with most of Google Apps. We foresee dozens, if not hundreds, of customers in a near future. All of them will be using their own Google domain and Google Apps.
While we could actually just deploy the application in our App Engine and modify the Cloud SQL tables to include the id of the customer who owns the record, we thought it would be better if we deploy an app instance and Cloud SQL for every one of them (on our own account). The main reasons coming to mind are that we can track how much every customer spends in terms of billing, and speed up the database since Cloud SQL is just a MySQL instance.

Steps for the creation would require editing a properties file in the packaged .war file, adding the certificate used to log in as a service account, and  probably something that I am missing at this moment :-P

This question is somehow related [Create an App Engine Project ID command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716697/create-an-app-engine-project-id-command-line?rq=1)

Comment: Creating projects on the developer computer should be possible, it's a matter of creating directories and files.  But I guess you really mean automated creation of new AppEngine applications... and I've never seen anything about how to do that.  Nevertheless, the Eclipse AppEngine plugin effectively does something similar.

Comment: @MartinBerends hehe, yes I meant creating the application on Google servers, not locally :-)

Comment: Are you aware that if you deploy the app under their account you also provide them the possibility to download your source code?

Comment: @JimmyKane yes, that's why our plan is to deploy their instances in our own account, but using their OAuth certificate in order to use the service account log in and impersonate their users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible (and is unlikely to be possible anytime soon).

Update:

I can see why splitting into separate projects for billing purposes would be really nice (multi-tenancy is great, but getting one bill per customer from Google sounds easier), but unfortunately I don't think that it's going to be your best option.

For AppEngine, you may want to look into the [multi-tenancy features](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy) (or [in Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/multitenancy)) and [how to get stats for billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793541/app-engine-multi-tenancy-ssl-and-billing).

Keep in mind however, CloudSQL is **not** simply a MySQL instance. It happens to speak MySQL but is not the same as running MySQL on Compute Engine for example. I would recommend that you run some benchmarks to be sure that the "adding the customer ID to the table" idea you had won't work.

Lastly, a possibly relevant read: http://signalvnoise.com/posts/1509-mr-moore-gets-to-punt-on-sharding

> I guess the conclusion is that there’s no use in preempting the technological progress of tomorrow. Machines will get faster and cheaper all the time, but you’ll still only have the same limited programming resources that you had yesterday.
>
> If you can spend them on adding stuff that users care about instead of prematurely optimizing for the future, you stand a better chance of being in business when that tomorrow finally rolls around.